# How to solve "Indexerror: too many indices for array" when importing data from a notepad

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am importing two columns of data from a notepad and attempting to plot them. The first column of data values (angle) ranges from 10 to 110 in increments of 0.1 and the second column (intensity) has one value for each corresponding angle increment. The error comes from the x = data_file[0,:] line.

and as requested here are some lines of the .dat file:

```
10.0    0.0
10.1    0.0
10.2    0.0
10.3    0.0
10.4    0.0
10.5    0.0
10.6    0.0
10.7    0.0
10.8    0.0
10.9    0.0
11.0    0.0
11.1    0.0
11.2    0.0
11.3    0.0
11.4    0.0
11.5    0.0
11.6    0.0
11.7    0.0
11.8    0.0
11.9    0.0
12.0    0.0
12.1    0.0
12.2    0.0
12.3    0.0
12.4    0.0
12.5    0.0
12.6    0.0
12.7    0.0
12.8    0.0
12.9    0.0
13.0    0.0
13.1    0.0
13.2    0.0
13.3    0.0
13.4    0.0
13.5    0.0
13.6    0.0
13.7    0.0
13.8    0.0
13.9    0.0
14.0    0.0
14.1    0.0
14.2    0.0
14.3    0.0
14.4    0.0
14.5    0.0
14.6    0.0
14.7    0.0
14.8    0.0
```

and

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file = np.genfromtxt('practice_data_py18ea.dat',delimiter = 'none')

x = data_file[0,:]
y = data_file[1,:]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Two Theta')
plt.ylabel('Counts per Second')
plt.title('Counts vs Two Theta')
plt.show()

data_file.close()
```

Comment: colud you please edit your question pasting some lines of your .dat file?

Comment: What's the `dtype` and `shape` of `data_file`

Comment: there are two columns of float values, hpaulj

Comment: If the delimiter is right (try omitting that parameter), `data_file` should be a (n,2) array.

Comment: check the shape of data_file, likely you are slicing wrong

Answer (score 0):

With a sample of your text:

```
In [44]: txt="""10.0    0.0 
    ...: 10.1    0.0 
    ...: 10.2    0.0 
    ...: 10.3    0.0 
    ...: 10.4    0.0 
    ...: 10.5    0.0 
    ...: 10.6    0.0 
    ...: 10.7    0.0 
    ...: 10.8    0.0""".splitlines()                                                           
In [45]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt)            # delimiter=None does the same thing                                                 
In [46]: data.shape                                                                            
Out[46]: (9, 2)
```

Indexing with `[0,:]` is wrong

```
In [49]: x = data[:,0]                                                                         
In [50]: x.shape                                                                               
Out[50]: (9,)
In [51]: x                                                                                     
Out[51]: array([10. , 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8])
```